# Align a matrix to a vector in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to visualize normals of triangles.
I have created a triangle to use as the visual representation of the normal but I'm having trouble aligning it to the normal.

I have tried using `glm::lookAt` but the triangle ends up in some weird position and rotation after that. I am able to move the triangle in the right place with `glm::translate` though.

Here is my code to create the triangle which is used for the visualization:

```
// xyz rgb
float vertex_data[] =
{
    0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.25f, 0.0f, 0.025f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.25f, 0.0f, -0.025f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
};

unsigned int index_data[] = {0, 1, 2};

glGenVertexArrays(1, &nrmGizmoVAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &nrmGizmoVBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &nrmGizmoEBO);

glBindVertexArray(nrmGizmoVAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nmrGizmoVBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex_data), vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, nrmGizmoEBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(index_data), index_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

and here is the code to draw the visualizations:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < worldTriangles->size(); i++)
{
    Triangle *tri = &worldTriangles->at(i);
    glm::vec3 wp = tri->worldPosition;
    glm::vec3 nrm = tri->normal;

    nrmGizmoMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    //nrmGizmoMatrix = glm::translate(nrmGizmoMatrix, wp);
    nrmGizmoMatrix = glm::lookAt(wp, wp + nrm, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));

    gizmoShader.setMatrix(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, nrmGizmoMatrix);
    glBindVertexArray(nrmGizmoVAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

When using only `glm::translate`, the triangles appear in right positions but all point in the same direction. How can I rotate them so that they point in the direction of the normal vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `lookAt` is intended to be used as the view matrix, thus it returns the transform from world space to local (camera) space. In your case you want the reverse -- from local (triangle) to world space. Taking an `inverse` of `lookAt` should solve that.

---

However, I'd take a step back and look at (haha) the bigger picture. What I notice about your approach:

- It's very inefficient -- you issue a separate call with a different model matrix **for every single normal**.
- You don't even need the entire model matrix. A triangle is a 2-d shape, so all you need is two basis vectors.

I'd instead generate all the vertices for the normals in a single array, and then use `glDrawArrays` to draw that. For the actual calculation, observe that we have one degree of freedom when it comes to aligning the triangle along the normal. Your `lookAt` code resolves that DoF rather arbitrary. A better  way to resolve that is to constrain it by requiring that it faces towards the camera, thus maximizing the visible area. The calculation is straightforward:

```
// inputs: vertices output array, normal position, normal direction, camera position
void emit_normal(std::vector<vec3> &v, const vec3 &p, const vec3 &n, const vec3 &c) {
    static const float length = 0.25f, width = 0.025f;
    vec3 t = normalize(cross(n, c - p)); // tangent
    v.push_back(p);
    v.push_back(p + length*n + width*t);
    v.push_back(p + length*n - width*t);
}

// ... in your code, generate normals through:
std::vector<vec3> normals;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < worldTriangles->size(); i++) {
    Triangle *tri = &worldTriangles->at(i);
    emit_normal(normals, tri->worldPosition, tri->normal, camera_position);
}

// ... create VAO for normals ...
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, normals.size());
```

Note, however, that this would make the normal mesh camera-dependent -- which is desirable when rendering normals with triangles. Most CAD software draws normals with lines instead, which is much simpler and avoids many problems:

```
void emit_normal(std::vector<vec3> &v, const vec3 &p, const vec3 &n) {
    static const float length = 0.25f;
    v.push_back(p);
    v.push_back(p + length*n);
}

// ... in your code, generate normals through:
std::vector<vec3> normals;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < worldTriangles->size(); i++) {
    Triangle *tri = &worldTriangles->at(i);
    emit_normal(normals, tri->worldPosition, tri->normal);
}

// ... create VAO for normals ...
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, normals.size());
```

Comment: How would I correctly take rotation into account when calculating normals of meshes' triangles? If I multiply the normals by the mesh matrix that has its position and rotation in it, the normals seems to be in correct orientation but somehow in a "inverted" position like this: https://i.imgur.com/MASTpty.png

Comment: @nyaol9: what's a 'mesh matrix'? is it 'world to local' or 'local to world'? Since position looks inverted, I'd guess it's 'world to local' and you really want the inverse of that (and the rotation is probably also inverted, but it's harder to notice). I recommend posting a new question with this problem and your current code.

Comment: "mesh matrix" was just bad naming on my end. It is actually the model matrix of the mesh. Taking the inverse of said matrix solved the problem. I'm still learning about all the different matrices and how to use them in situations like this.

Comment: @nyaol9: happy you figured it out! I think you need to pay more attention to what direction your matrices transform: **local to world** or **world to local**. Model matrices are usually **local to world**, so it is suspicious that yours is inverted..? How do you apply it in the vertex shader then? The math there should be identical to what you do for the normals.

Comment: in the vertex shader it is applied like this: `gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vPos, 1.0);`

Comment: Turns out that everything was fixed simply by changing the multiplication order in the triangle calculations. No need to use a inverted model matrix anymore. I did not think of this before because I read somewhere that the order is `vector * matrix` but that doesn't work here. **How do I know which order to use in different situations?** Feeling kinda dumb now since the correct order was visible in the shader all this time. Should have realized it sooner when you mentoined it (and I even copied it into a comment here...)

Comment: @nyaol9 OpenGL ecosystem assumes that vectors are columns -- thus you multiply matrices on the left: `matrix * vector`. If you think of your vectors as rows (some libraries do), then all your matrices would be **transposed**: `matrix*vector == vector*transpose(matrix)`. It's a mathematical fact that transposition is very similar to inversion (for rotation matrices it is the same thing), so it explains why it seemed like inversion helped.

Comment: @nyaol9 How do you know? Read the docs or the source code for the respective libraries. Learn how to derive all those matrices yourself, so you can compare their math with yours. I think that function names `lookAt`, `translate`, `rotate`, etc. are horribly confusing and non-descriptive: you cannot tell by their name which direction they transform (local to global or vice versa), or if they assume column or row vectors.